# How to install conda-pack environment on Window OS

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

I have packed the conda environment from one Window Server to another one with no internet connection Window server with conda-pack library with the format of ZIP. Yet, I am not sure how to unpack the environment and register it on the anaconda. It seems the code provided by conda-pack provide is bash but not Window commound prompt.

Thank you for your assistance[image: Reference]
https://www.anaconda.com/moving-conda-environments/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
# Activate the environment. This adds `my_env/bin` to your path
$ source my_env/bin/activate
```

Use

```
$ my_env\Scripts\activate.bat
```